# how to get user/sender email id in Microsoft bot-framework activity?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, mbf

Is there any way to get sender/user email id in bot-framework request?

I'm able to get sender name in activity but any other way to get email id along with name and conversion id?

Comment: How did you get your token? You can achieve it using [Microsoft graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: @DanaV microsoft teams

Answer (score 1):

As @md-farid-uddin-kiron said, you can use Graph. There is a sample that pretty much has this already setup. Please check [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/4770a37622e0ec7d7840dbe370e10ee73bee7b79/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth/Dialogs/MainDialog.cs#L65) (I linked to a specific line for an example).

The conversation ID can be retrieved by:
`stepContext.Context.Activity.Conversation.Id`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can see that Bot Framework makes it possible to get information from Teams channel quite easily. First, in your code add the following `using` statement:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Teams;
```

Then use the following lines inside the code where you want to get sender's data:

```
var members = await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
var userData = "";
foreach (var teamMember in members)
{
    if (teamMember.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
    {
        userData = $"AadObjectId: {teamMember.AadObjectId}, Email: {teamMember.Email}, GivenName: {teamMember.GivenName}, Name: {teamMember.Name}, Role: {teamMember.Role}, Surname: {teamMember.Surname}, TenantId: {teamMember.TenantId}, UserPrincipalName: {teamMember.UserPrincipalName}, UserRole: {teamMember.UserRole}";
    }
}
```

The `members` variable will contain 2 elements: one represents the bot, and the other one represents the sender (human user). This snippet build the `userData` string variable which contains values of all properties available in the `teamMember` object.

EDIT: if you can't access the `turnContext` object and instead you can access the `stepContext` object (they're present in Bot Framework's EchoBot and CoreBot, respectively), just replace `turnContext` in the code snippet I attached with `stepContext.Context`.